# Video encoding on Raspberry Pi 4 via ffmpeg and h264_v4l2m2m produces corrupted video

Tags: pi-4, video, raspberry-pi-os, ffmpeg, h264

- Raspberry Pi 4, 4 GB
- Rapsberry Pi OS Lite, 64 bit (2022-09-22)
- Kernel 5.15.61-v8+
- ffmpeg 4.3.4-0+deb11u1+rpt3

`config.txt` has the following relevant entry:

```
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```

According to my research, it would seem that the RPI4 is capable of hardware-accelerated video encoding using ffmpeg (from v4.3 on) via the `h264_v4lm2m2` codec. `ffmpeg -codecs` and `ffmpeg -encoders` shows this codec to be available. [Other](https://www.willusher.io/general/2020/11/15/hw-accel-encoding-rpi4) [people](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8604777.html?sid=053fa0c5074f97856bbe55e64ac97fa0) with a similar setup have gotten this to work successfully.

When I try this:

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4 -c:v h264_v4l2m2m -c:a copy out.mp4
```

It gives me two warnings (see last two lines), but proceeds to encode the file anyway:

```
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x557353b190]  <<< v4l2_encode_init: fmt=0/-1
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x557353b190] Using device /dev/video11
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x557353b190] driver 'bcm2835-codec' on card 'bcm2835-codec-encode' in mplane mode
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x557353b190] requesting formats: output=YU12 capture=H264
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x557353b190] Failed to set number of B-frames: Invalid argument
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x557353b190] Failed to set gop size: Invalid argument
```

Hardware acceleration seems to work, as it encodes at ~130 fps. However, the resulting file is corrupted and can't be played.

What am I missing?

Comment: @jsotola Not sure if warnings or errors, as it doesn't specify. Either way, those are the only indication of something potentially going wrong. And good catch - they are indeed. I've changed my wording accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got this to work by swapping out the `ffmpeg` provided by `apt` and instead compiling the fork by jc-kynesim, which can be found at [github.com/jc-kynesim/rpi-ffmpeg](https://github.com/jc-kynesim/rpi-ffmpeg).

With this, it works, although I still get the following warning/ error:

```
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x556ff3d430] Failed to set gop size: Invalid argument
```

The encoding was a bit slower than before, clocking in at ~100 fps.

I don't know if the reason this fixed the problem is because this version of ffmpeg contains patches that solve the underlying problem, or if installing the numerous packages required for compilation actually brought in additional dependencies that were missing before. I've created an [issue report on GitHub](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/ffmpeg/issues/6).

Comment: How to recompile `ffmpeg` using `rpi-ffmpeg`?

Comment: @Hassaan clone/ download rpi-ffmpeg, then look up a [compilation guide for ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) and work through it accordingly.